# Can T in template <typename T> use inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want to do something like this:

```
template <typename T:public Vertex> addTri( T v1, T v2, T v3 )
{
    // Take v1.pos, v2.pos, v3.pos and create a geometric repn..
    Triangle tri( v1.pos, v2.pos, v3.pos ) ; // all vertices will 
    // have to have a .pos member.

    // Create the vertex buffer..
    VertexBuffer<T> vb ...
}
```

Since that doesn't work, this is my workaround..

```
template <typename T> addTri( T v1, T v2, T v3 )
{        
    Vertex* p1 = (Vertex*)&v1 ;
    // This is a very "shut up C++, I know what I'm doing" type cast.
    // I'd like for C++ to know that all vertex types (T in this case)
    // __will__ have a Vector member .pos.

    Triangle tri( p1->pos, p2->pos, p3->pos ) ; 
    // Create the vertex buffer..
    VertexBuffer<T> vb ...
}
```

### Background

In case you're interested, I'm trying to write a general bit of code to handle triangle creation.
Each vertex has to have a `.pos` member, because each vertex has to have a position in space.

However not every vertex type will have a texture coordinate.  Not every vertex will have a color.  Hence the parameterized types.

A similar approach is used in XNA [`VertexBuffer.SetData<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198836.aspx).

Comment: It's not clear what the problem here is (other than the pseudo-syntax for the first example is obviously invalid).  The first and second examples don't look the same at all.  What are you doing with `p1`?  Where are you creating the `Triangle` in the second example?

Comment: Yes, the Tri would have to be created using `p1`.  Added in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot specify a type restriction in the template type argument. However, generally, you don't have to.

If you simply do:

```
template <typename T> addTri( T v1, T v2, T v3 )
{
    Vertex &v1r = v1;
    // ....
}
```

This will work if the function is instantiated with a derivative of Vertex. It will create an (obscure) error if `T &` is *not* convertible to `Vertex &`.

If you don't even care if the types are convertible to `Vertex` as long as they have the same members, you can even skip the assignment - C++ template arguments essentially work using [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing); if you do `v1.x`, and `T` contains a member named `x`, then it will work, whatever type `T` might actually be.

You can be a bit more sophisticated using boost's [type-traits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) and a [static assertion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html); with this, you can start defining an assertion to make the error a bit easier to understand:

```
template <typename T> addTri( T v1, T v2, T v3 )
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(boost::is_convertible<T&, Vertex&>::value,
        "Template argument must be a subclass of Vertex");
    Vertex &v1r = v1;
    // ....
}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, one ***can*** specify a restriction on a template parameter, for example, making use of `boost::enable_if` and `boost::is_base_and_derived`

Comment: +1.  I'm also a big fan of boost::is_base_of(), which performs a similar check.

Comment: is_base_of looks at private bases, however, which is not what we want here

Comment: @Armen, in practice all that does is changes from one type of obscure error message to another type of obscure error message :)

Comment: I'm avoiding boost dependencies

Comment: @bobobobo, in VS2010 `is_convertible` is available in the `std` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982501.aspx . You can also replace `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG` with `static_assert` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293588.aspx)

Comment: @bdonlan: Ha ha, good point about one obscuring message replacing the other :))

Comment: Sometimes you just have to remember that templates are just really complicated macros for _generating_ the text of code.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of `enable_if`, `is_base_of` and `is_convertible` typetraits should do the job:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo : public std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<YourBase, T>::value &&
                                   std::is_convertible<T&, A&>::value,
                    T>::type
{
  // consider "using YourBase::foo;" directives here
};
```

The type traits are available from `<type_traits>` in modern compilers, or `<tr1/type_traits>` or Boost otherwise.

Comment: is_base_of will return a true value even if `YourBase` is an _inaccessible_ (ie, private or protected) base of `T`

Comment: @bdolan: Fair enough. I added an `is_convertible` check, how's that?

Comment: I don't see any is_convertible check there... :)

Comment: @bdonlan: Look into your heart, and you will find :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> 
void addTri(T v1, T v2, T v3, char (*)[is_base_of<Vertex, T>::value] = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

to disable the generation of `addTri` if `T` doesn't inherit from `Vertex`. But you don't need it to be able to use the `pos` member.

**Update:** Actually `std::is_base_of` will return true if `Vertex` is an inaccessible base class of `T`. Use the following implementation of `is_base_of` instead:

```
template <typename B, typename D>
struct is_base_of 
{
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<D*, B*>::value
        && std::is_class<B>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use your first solution without the odd `:public Vertex`. When you instantiate it with a `Vertex` or with something that just has a `pos` member, it will be fine. C++ doesn't have to know that every `T` has a `pos` member. If you anytime instantiate the template with anything that has no `pos` member, you will get a compiler error, otherwise it's fine.

What you're looking for is concepts, but they have been dropped from the C++0x standard, I think.

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking at templates wrong.  What you describe looks to be handled better by good ole-fashioned inheritance.  Instead of passing instances of your object, try passing pointers instead like this:

```
addTri( Vertex *v1, Vertex *v2, Vertex *v3 )
{
    // Take v1.pos, v2.pos, v3.pos and create a geometric repn..
    Triangle tri( v1->pos, v2->pos, v3->pos ) ; // all vertices will 
    // have to have a .pos member.

    // Create the vertex buffer..
    VertexBuffer<T> vb ...
}
```

Then just pass pointers to your inheriting objects (casting as the parent class as necessary)

Comment: Yeah but you don't know `<T>` when it comes time to create the vertexbuffer `VertexBuffer<T> vb`