# template <typename T> perculating all through the code

Tags: c++, templates

I [templatized a class earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210944/can-t-in-template-typename-t-use-inheritance/7210968) and as a result of this templatization, *all classes that received objects of this newly templated type require templating as well*, even where the  templatization is completely irrelevant.

So:

- `class Shape` is the base class for `class Sphere`, `Cube`, `Model`
- Each `Shape` contains a `Mesh`
- `Mesh` has now been templatized to allow for basically the VertexBuffer to have a parameterized type:

So:

```
template <typename T> struct Mesh
{
    VertexBuffer<T> verts ; // Mesh needs to be templated to allow
    // the vertex buffer to be templated as well
} ;
```

So now the class that contains the `Mesh` (base class `Shape`) needs to be templated as well:

```
template <typename T> class Shape
{
    Mesh<T>* mesh ;
} ;
```

**And now**, *all* the methods anywhere in the code need to be templated *as well*, even where that templatization in no way affects the code (ie that code has no business with the vertex type of the Mesh member)

So for example, the octree node:

```
// An octree node
template <typename T> struct ONode // but this class doesn't really benefit
                                   // from templatization
{
    AABB bounds ;
    ONode* parent ; // facilitate movement thru the tree
    ONode* children[8]; // cells, octants, cubelets
    Shape<T>* objects ;    // for the purposes of the Octree,
                        // But ALL SHAPES BEHAVE THE SAME. <T> serves no purpose
```

This is a really nasty artifact and I'm not sure how to stop the perculation of templatization *at an earlier point*, or if templatization was a correct choice now that I see how much needs to be templatized.

Comment: Does VertexBuffer need to be a template? Perhaps VertexBuffer could be a non-template class having a few template member functions. It would be helpful if you showed what VertexBuffer looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you create a non-templated base class for `Mesh` (or `VertexBuffer`, whichever makes the most sense) that exposes the functionality that doesn't depend on the template, and use that in other places. For example:

```
class MeshBase
{
    // Functionality that doesn't depend on the template type.
};

template<typename T>
class Mesh : public MeshBase
{
    // Functionality that does depend on the template type.
};
```

This does mean that you may more frequently need to deal with dynamically allocated values of this type and pass them around as pointers, but some judicious use of smart pointers should alleviate that burden.

---

In general, there is a certain friction between using object oriented principles and generic programming principles, some of which you've discovered here. Whenever this happens, you essentially need a class that can hold the value of multiple generic types and models the common behavior, without the consumer needing to know the templated type. Sometimes, this can be done even if the types have no common base. This technique is called type erasure and [this article by Thomas Becker](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) provides some insight into this matter.

Comment: Or similarly for VertexBuffer, since in this example that is what drove the "template percolation" in the first place.

Comment: Yes, good point. You can do this at any point where it makes the most sense. :)

Comment: @Nemo I ended up doing exactly that.  So __type erasure__ is it?

Comment: I found out the way t